# Excel, reading formula of colorscale conditional formatting rule

Tags: office-js

I'm trying to do a search through all formulas in conditional formatting rules. I have this function for that (I know, too big, I'm just trying to get this to work):

```
async function SearchInFormatConditions(
  context,
  wb: Excel.Workbook,
  sht: Excel.Worksheet,
  searchString: string,
  matchComplete: boolean,
  matchCase: boolean
) {
  let foundRules = new foundCollection();
  let rng = sht.getUsedRange();
  let cfRules = rng.conditionalFormats;
  let cfCt = cfRules.getCount();
  await context.sync();
  for (let i = 0; i < cfCt.value; i++) {
    let cf = cfRules.getItemAt(i);
    let cfRange = cf.getRange().load("address");
    let customcfRule = cf.customOrNullObject;
    let cellValueRule = cf.cellValueOrNullObject;
    await context.sync();
    if (cellValueRule) {
      cellValueRule.load();
      await context.sync();
      let ruleFormula1;
      let ruleFormula2;
      try {
        ruleFormula1 = cellValueRule.rule.formula1;
      } catch {
        ruleFormula1 = "";
      }
      try {
        ruleFormula2 = cellValueRule.rule.formula2;
      } catch {
        ruleFormula2 = "";
      }
      if (ruleFormula1 + "|" + ruleFormula2 !== "|") {
        if (Instr(ruleFormula1, searchString, matchCase, matchComplete)) {
          foundRules.newFoundItem(
            "formatCondition formula 1",
            ruleFormula1,
            "formatCondition formula 1 in " + cfRange.address,
            sht,
            cfRange,
            ruleFormula1
          );
        }
        if (ruleFormula2.length > 0) {
          if (Instr(ruleFormula2, searchString, matchCase, matchComplete)) {
            foundRules.newFoundItem(
              "formatCondition formula 2",
              ruleFormula2,
              "formatCondition formula 2 in " + cfRange.address,
              sht,
              cfRange,
              ruleFormula2
            );
          }
        }
      }
      if (customcfRule && ruleFormula1 + "|" + ruleFormula2 == "|") {
        let cfRule = customcfRule.rule;
        cfRule.load();
        await context.sync();
        try {
          let cfRuleFormula = cfRule.formula;
        } catch {
          let cfRuleFormula = null;
        }
        if (cfRule.formula) {
          if (Instr(cfRule.formula, searchString, matchCase, matchComplete)) {
            foundRules.newFoundItem(
              "formatCondition formula",
              cfRule.formula,
              "formatCondition formula in " + cfRange.address,
              sht,
              cfRange,
              cfRule.formula
            );
          }
        } else {
          let colorScaleCF = cf.colorScaleOrNullObject;
          await context.sync();
          if (colorScaleCF) {
            colorScaleCF.load();
            await context.sync();
            console.log("colorscale " + cfRange.address);
            let min = null;
            let max = null;
            try {
              let max = colorScaleCF.criteria.maximum.formula;
            } catch {
            }
            try {
              let min = colorScaleCF.criteria.minimum.formula;
            } catch {
            }
            if (min) {
              if (min.formula.length > 0) {
                if (Instr(min.formula, searchString, matchCase, matchComplete)) {
                  foundRules.newFoundItem(
                    "formatCondition min formula",
                    min.formula,
                    "formatCondition min formula in " + cfRange.address,
                    sht,
                    cfRange,
                    min.formula
                  );
                }
              }
            }
            if (max) {
              if (max.formula.length > 0) {
                if (Instr(max.formula, searchString, matchCase, matchComplete)) {
                  foundRules.newFoundItem(
                    "formatCondition max formula",
                    max.formula,
                    "formatCondition max formula in " + cfRange.address,
                    sht,
                    cfRange,
                    max.formula
                  );
                }
              }
            }
            //            console.log(min.formula + "|" + max.formula);
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
  return foundRules;
}
```

when the code arrives here:

```
  let colorScaleCF = cf.colorScaleOrNullObject;
  await context.sync();
  if (colorScaleCF) {
```

even when the range in question does not have a colorscale CF rule set up (it has a databar rule!) the statement if (colorScaleCF) yields True.

Moreover, when the range does have a colorscale rule, the code fails to read the colorScaleCF.criteria.maximum.formula.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

colorScaleCF is a proxy object and it will always be defined once you set it to cf.colorScaleOrNullObject.

Instead of testing with if (colorScaleCF) {...}, you should test with if (!colorScaleCF.isNullObject) {...}.

Comment: Interesting. Why do these statements work then:
` let cellValueRule = cf.cellValueOrNullObject;
    await context.sync();
    if (cellValueRule)`

Comment: Your suggestion works if I remove the ():
`if (!colorScaleCF.isNullObject)`

Comment: Oh yes. My mistake. I fixed it in the answer.